# Signalr 2.0 user and session data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, adfs

i have a MVC application that contains an ASPX page that will be called in single sign on mode.

How can i set the user that is passed by a request call? 
I tried to use "Identity" with no fortune.

example:

```
            string username = "MyUsername";
        string userid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"); //could be a constant

        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>{
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", username), 
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", userid)};
        var genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        genericIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
        var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, new string[] { "aaa" });
        Context.User = genericPrincipal;
```

The second problem is that i have some data regarding the user but i can't set to session (like expected by signalr design). 
How can solve it?

Update:
After some search i understand what i really need. When the page is called i check validation of user on database and if it's verified i need to store this information in a way that is reachable everywhere. It's what i would have done with SESSION object.
For me a user is not a simple string, but it's a complex object that contains useful information for the behaviour of the program.
I hope i am clearer.

Comment: if you solved your problem, you should post it as an answer and accept

Comment: I have not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add state on the client proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#passstate).
If your data is too complex for that, you need to pass it at apprpriate times using hub methods.